# What is the use case of the Property class in android

Tags: android

I just noticed the Property class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Property.html . I can see some explanation of it here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html#api but dont really understand the use cases of it. Would be great if someone can point me to some code snippets where I can understand this more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property is a wrapper to a Reflection.

For example, you have an object

```
public class A {
    private int fieldOfA;
    private int fieldTwo;
    private int fieldThree;

    public void setFieldOfA(int a) {
        fieldOfA = a;
    }

    public int getFieldOfA() {
        return fieldOfA;
    }

    public void setFieldTwo(int a) {
        fieldTwo = a;
    }

    public int getFieldTwo() {
        return fieldTwo;
    }

    public void setFieldThree(int a) {
        fieldThree = a;
    }

    public int getFieldThree() {
        return fieldThree;
    }
}
```

If you need to update phew fields, you have to know all their names in the update method without Properties

```
private void updateValues(final A a, final int value) {
    a.setFieldOfA(value);
    a.setFieldTwo(value);
    a.setFieldThree(value);
}
```

With Properties you can update only the properties.

```
Property aProperty = Property.of(A.class, int.class, "fieldOfA");
Property bProperty = Property.of(A.class, int.class, "fieldTwo");
Property cProperty = Property.of(A.class, int.class, "fieldThree");

Collection<Property<A, Integer>> properties = new HashSet<>();
properties.add(aProperty);
properties.add(bProperty);
properties.add(cProperty);

updateValues(a, 10, properties);
```

And the method would be

```
private void updateValues(final A a, final int value, final Collection<Property<A, Integer>> properties) {
    for (final Property<A, Integer> property : properties) {
        property.set(a, value);
    }
}
```

As laalto memtioned, property animations use a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

One example would be [property animations.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) The Property class provides an abstraction for attributes that can be changed over time to perform an animation.